# Oracle Triggers reflect only in one of the windows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

One of my triggers works only in one instance/window of oracle. Can someone explain why? PFB the details that I am trying with:

```
SQL> sho parameter db_name

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_name                              string      XE
SQL> sho user
USER is "AMAR"
SQL> update employees set salary=1505 where empname='amar1505';
Old salary: 15005  New salary: 1505  Difference -13500

1 row updated.

SQL> update employees set salary=1505 where empname='amar1505';
Old salary: 1505  New salary: 1505  Difference 0

1 row updated.

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18-MAY-17 09.56.50.900000 AM +05:30

SQL> select count(*) from employees;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       106
*===============================================================================*

Other instance:

SQL> sho parameter db_name;

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_name                              string      XE
SQL> sho user
USER is "AMAR"
SQL> update employees set salary=15043 where empname='amar1503';

1 row updated.

SQL> select systimestamp from dual;

SYSTIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
18-MAY-17 09.58.25.386000 AM +05:30

SQL> select count(*) from employees;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       106
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply need to check whether `SERVEROUTPUT` is enabled; for example:

```
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line('something');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line('something');
  3  end;
  4  /
something

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```